# How to control Volume on Apple Watch Bluetooth Audio

Tags: audio, bluetooth, apple-watch, volume

I recently developed an app that runs on the Apple Watch. It plays audio clips that you can hear on your BlueTooth headphones or speakers connected to your watch. I tested the app with a set of speakers and headphones, both of which had their own volume control. Everything was fine, so I submitted and was accepted into the Apple App Store.

When Apple AirPods came out, I tried using them with my app. The volume in the AirPods is very low and there does not seem to be any way to control their volume when they are connected to the Apple Watch. I tried using Siri to control the volume, but that works only when the AirPods are connected to the phone, not the watch.

When they are connected to the phone, you can also use phone's own volume controls.

I use WKAudioFilePlayer class to play the clips. There does not seem to be any way to control the volume from the software side either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move to [AVAudio​Player](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer), there you have volume API.